# Error when installing dbt-core from requirements.txt via git

Tags: python, pip, dbt

Please help!

I have an issue when I try to install dbt-core from requirements.txt with `git` prefix. What do I do:

1. In the project root create file requirements.txt.
2. Add to the file the following content:

```
dbt-core @ git+https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core.git@v1.6.0#subdirectory=core
```

3. Run the following command in the project root:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And after that I get error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: dbt-core
  Building wheel for dbt-core (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [549 lines of output]
            ...
      copying build\lib\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\incremental\on_schema_change.sql -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\incremental
      copying build\lib\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\incremental\strategies.sql -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\incremental
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\materialized_view
      copying build\lib\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\materialized_view\alter_materialized_view.sql -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\materialized_view
      copying build\lib\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\materialized_view\create_materialized_view.sql -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\materialized_view
      copying build\lib\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\materialized_view\get_materialized_view_configuration_changes.sql -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\materialized_view
      error: could not create 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\dbt\include\global_project\macros\materializations\models\materialized_view\get_materialized_view_configuration_changes.sql': No such file or directory
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dbt-core
  Running setup.py clean for dbt-core
Failed to build dbt-core
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dbt-core, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried to run the last command with flags like `--no-cache-dir`, `--no-binary`, but it does not work.

Previous versions (<1.6) install correctly.

**Note: I need to install dbt-core exactly with git because I have my own fork of dbt-core and I need to install it.** So the installation without git does not fit for me...

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue is connected with setuptools version compatibility.

I had the same problem, unfortunately I failed to install dbt-core from requirements.txt, but you can do it directly using pip command:

pip install git+https://github.com/SOVALINUX/dbt-core.git@v1.6.100#subdirectory=core

It is not perfect but this solution worked for me.